# How to call custom dll in multithreads in powershell?

Tags: multithreading, powershell, dll

I have a custom dll, and right now in my multi-thread codes, I am referencing this dll by:

....

```
$threads = 6

for ($i2 = 0; $i2 -lt $threads)
    {
        Copy-Item myCmdlet.dll $i2.dll
        $i2++
    }
for ($i = 0; $i -lt $threads) 
{
    $jobs += Start-job -ScriptBlock $ScriptBlock -ArgumentList ($i)
}
```

....

```
$ScriptBlock = {
    param($i)
            Installutil $i.dll
            Get-PSSnapIn -Registered
            Add-PSSnapIn MyCmdletSet

            $result = Get-MyCmdlet
            ....
}
```

....

This would be annoying because I may end up with many copies of the original dll. Is it any other way to call a dll in multi-threading mechanism?

Thanks for all answers!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're on PowerShell v2 or higher, you don't need to install/register snapins anymore.  Just use `Import-Module -Path <path-to-dll>`.  So your scripblock would look like:

```
$ScriptBlock = {
    param($i)

    Import-Module c:\somepath\mycmdlet.dll

    $result = Get-MyCmdlet
    ....
}
```